# Build error after upgrading to Visual Studio Update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

After upgrading to Visual Studio Update 2, my C# program fails to build with:

> "Error in occurred while signing: Root element is missing".

No file is listed in that column of the output. I've seen the other posts about the "Root element is missing", but they know which file has the problem.

If it's talking about the certificate file, that's a binary.

Any thoughts?

PS - when I right-click on the error and select 'Show Error Help', it sends me to [this URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSBuild.SignFile.SignToolError);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6)&rd=true) which doesn't include my error message.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141763/an-error-occurred-while-signing-unknown-error-2147012894

Comment: That looked like the answer, but after going through that solution, the same error ended up coming up. In fact, I got a couple others.  :-(

Comment: Don't rely on the **Error List** panel. Also inspect the **Output** panel. When in doubt, increase the verbose mode.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but where do I set verbose mode? Thanks!

Comment: OK, Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->Drop Down does this. Now I just need to figure out what the out is telling me. Thanks, Uwe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out. I had to uncheck the box for signing the program, then run it again, then re-check the box, and run it again. From here, it now builds. Before doing all of that, I did reset the signature file, which likely helped. Strange, but better now.

Thanks, All!